# Override spring kakfka version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-kafka, dependency-management

How to include the particular version of spring kafka. Kafka version dependency is 2.5.14 imported by the starter parent. But I want to override it with 2.6.10 version
How can I do it?

This is my Spring Boot starter

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Kafka version dependency is 2.5.14 .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#update-deps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your project `pom.xml` file override `spring-kafka.version` property value to give desired version.
And if you want to override `kafka` libraries version in the same way you can override `kafka.version` property value.

```
<properties>
    <spring-kafka.version><!-- desired spring-kafka version--></spring-kafka.version>
    <kafka.version><!-- desired kafka version--></kafka.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: This is indeed the way **but** I would strongly suggest to add a warning as you might be pulling in incompatible dependencies due to this. Newer versions of a library often have newer versions of dependencies (like spring) which might lead to incompatible versions or mixed versions which will at some point bite you. As the user is on Spring Boot 2.3 it is probably better to upgrade to a newer Spring BOot version which would include those newer dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum Correct .But if u read spring kafka version doc its 2.6.* version is compatible with  Spring bOot 2.3.* .And due to some reason i cant use latest sprng boot version

Comment: See the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview) for the compatibility matrix; 2.6 (currently 2.6.10) is indeed compatible with Boot 2.3.x. Bear in mind, though, that Boot 2.3 is out of Open Source support and will go end of life in February. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions Also refer to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.10/reference/html/#update-deps) if you want to override the kafka-clients version prescribed by Boot.